# Как заставить регулярное выражение возвращать только первое совпадение?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

у меня есть строка

```
$s = '200x2000^3434^54545|120x400^3333^4444';
```

мне надо регулярной получить первую секцию между двух символов ^ ^

тестирую пока так:

```
echo preg_replace('/\^(.*?)\^/', 'XXXXX', $s);
```

но во первых оно захватывает и обе ^ и так же действует до конца строки

а мне надо что бы получилось так: 200x2000^XXXXX^54545|120x400^3333^4444

в гугле пишут что мне надо сделать символ * "не жадным а ленивым" но я всё не могу разобраться как это реализовать, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте аргумент *limit* со значением `1`:

```php
preg_replace('/\^[^^]*\^/', 'XXXXX', $str, 1) # Если нужно удалить символы ^
preg_replace('/(?<=\^)[^^]*(?=\^)/', 'XXXXX', $str, 1) # Если нужно сохранить символы ^ и заменить только текст внутри них
```

См. [пример кода на PHP](https://3v4l.org/WmhUX). См. [справку по `preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php):

> **limit**
> Максимально возможное количество замен каждого шаблона для каждой строки *subject*. По умолчанию равно `-1` (без ограничений).

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/dAcNlH/2/):

- `\^` - символ `^`
- `[^^]*` - ноль и более символов, отличных от `^`
- `\^` - символ `^`

**Альтернативное решение**

Если у вас нет возможности задать дополнительные аргументы для `preg_replace`, используйте

```php
$str = preg_replace('/^[^^]*\^\K[^^]*(?=\^)/', 'XXXXX', $str);
```

См. [пример этого регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/dAcNlH/3/). **Подробности**:

- `^` - начало строки
- `[^^]*` - ноль и более символов, отличных от `^`
- `\^` - символ `^`
- `\K` - оператор, удаляющий весь текст из буфера текущего совпадения
- `[^^]*` - ноль и более символов, отличных от `^`
- `(?=\^)` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который требует наличия символа `^` сразу после текущей позиции в строке.

Comment: спасибо! а как сделать что бы он не захватывал ^ а заменял между ними, ещё желательно что бы без доболнительных опций для функции мне скорей всего придетося этот патерн использоваться в SQL запросах

Comment: @dantelol Тогда `preg_replace('/(?<=\^)[^^]*(?=\^)/', 'XXXXX', $str, 1)`.

Comment: Да просто добавьте их в replacement.

Comment: @dantelol Можно и с помощью захватывающих подмасок: `preg_replace('/^([^^]*\^)[^^]*(\^)/', '${1}XXXXX$2', $str)`

Comment: @dantelol Если вам нужно сделать подобное в SQL, вам следует задать новый вопрос. Там следует указать, какую RDBMS вы используете. Обратите внимание на то, что в MSSQL / TSQL нет поддержки регулярных выражений для поиска и замены, там придётся выкручиваться с помощью UDF.

Answer (score 1):

Заменить первое вхождение можно явно, добавив якорь начала строки:

```
$s = '200x2000^3434^54545|120x400^3333^4444';

echo preg_replace('#^([^^]*\^)(?:[^^]*)#', '${1}XXX', $s);
```

- `^([^^]*\^)` - От начала строки до первого символа ^, включая его
- `(?:[^^]*)` - Некоторое количество не ^
- `$1` - Подставить в замену первую группу захвата

> 200x2000^XXX^54545|120x400^3333^4444

Comment: спасибо! а можно как то это ${1} добавить в регулярное выражение - я хочу это в sql использовать

Answer (score 1):

решил похожую задачу вот так (от начала строки дошел до первого нужного символа, после добавляется число а символ и все что до него удаляется с помощью \K):  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)